# Get the number of characters in a line of a p tag?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some text , a part of which I want to put inside a `<p>` tag.

HTML:

```html
<p id="mainTargetP">

</p>
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
 var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. a a a  Nullam nec magna eu dui pharetra bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at urna mi."
 var mainTargetP = document.getElementById('mainTargetP') ;
 // mainTargetP.innerHTML = get a part of text into P.
```

The `<p>` tag has been given a width, height, font size etc.

What I have is a large block of text, that I am dividing into paras of fixed width and height. The exact thing I have to figure out is how much text (how many words) from the block of text will fit nicely inside the para. Say if the para has 7 lines , I want to fit in exactly 7 lines of text. Not 6.5 lines , not 7.5 lines. Possible?

Basically I don't want any whitespace to be left in the last line, like this:

[image]

Makeshift solution that works with some blocks of text:

```javascript
var charsInLine = 63 ;
var lines = 7
var charsinTargetP = charInLine * lines - 20 ; 
var mainTargetP = document.getElementById('mainTargetP') ;

var s1 =text.substring(0,charsinTargetP ) ;
var nextPara = s1.lastIndexOf(' ')
mainTargetP.innerHTML = s1.substring(0,nextPara ) ;
```

Above the -20 value I am taking randomly. Sometimes the value needs to be -40 .

Hope I was clear, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn´t it be enough to just truncate large texts and use CSS to hide and transform the text to fit within the container element using `max-height` and `text-align: justify`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight-forward way that comes to mind is to temporarily set the paragraph's height to `auto`, put one character in it, take its height, and then keep appending characters until the height suddenly increased, indicating that it had word-wrapped. Then remove individual characters (or words, whatever) until the height went back to its original value, and set the height again (since you said the height was defined). Rinse, repeat for the following lines (since they won't have the same number of characters, not unless you're using a fixed-width font).

Comment: @user161179: Unless you're doing hundreds of lines on IE, I wouldn't expect a problem, but the only way to know for sure is to try it with your target browsers.

Comment: just did it, this solution worked just fine. and definitely no performance hit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is jQuery based solution.

HTML:

```
<p class="target font"></p>
<p class="target font"></p><!-- create as many tags as many pages you want -->
```

CSS:

```
.target {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.font {
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: justify
}
```

JS:

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. a a a  Nullam nec magna eu dui pharetra bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at urna mi.";
// element which will be appended to the end of each p tag and will cause line break
var justify = ' <span style="visibility:hidden;">something_very_very_very_long</span>';

var p = $('.target');
var q = $('<p class="font"></p>"');
q.css('width', p.width() + 'px');
q.text(text);

$(document.body).append(q);

var h = p.height();

var newText = text;
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < p.length; ++i) {
    while (q.height() > h) {
        newText = newText.substr(0, newText.lastIndexOf(' '));
        q.text(newText);
    }
    $(p[i]).html(newText + justify);

    j += newText.length + 1;
    newText = text.substr(j);
    q.html(newText);
}

q.detach();
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/9BBPA/7/

Comment: Please put the relevant code here as well, we can't depend on external sources.